# Get TypeError when call the function from second time

Tags: python

My problem is the error message only happen after I call the function second time
numLen, phoneMask = numberLen(3)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Here is my code.
If I type in correct extension, for example 71023 at first time I run the script, there is no problem.
If I typed wrong extension at first time and typed in correct one the second time, it return the typeerror message and I can see numberlen(i) returned none.

Thank you in advance.

```
import sys


def numAssign(t):

  maskList = ['02694406XX',  '02693710XX']
  extList = ['706XX',  '710XX']
  i = 0
  while i < len(extList) :
    if t != extList[i] :
        i = i + 1
    else :
        return True, maskList[i]

  print('''The extension you entered is not in the indial range.''')        
  return False, ' '




def numberLen(i):

    t = input('Please enter the extnsion : ')
    T = len(t)
    isNum = t.isdecimal()
    patternConvert = t[0:3] + 'XX'

    if T == 5 and isNum == True :
        valid, mask = numAssign(patternConvert)
        print(mask)
        print(i)
        if valid == True:
            print(numAssign(patternConvert))
            return True, mask
        else :
            if i == 0 :
                print('''The number you entered was not valid.
                         It has to be 5 digits.''')
            else :
                print('Please try again')
                print(i)
                numberLen(i-1)

    else :
        if i == 0 :
            print('Your entering is invalid, we will terminiate the programe')
            exit()
        else :
            numberLen(i-1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    numLen, phoneMask = numberLen(3)
    print(phoneMask)enter code here
```

Comment: What's the full error with trace?

Comment: And `numberLen` doesn't always return anything; in fact it returns nothing in most cases. In the cases where it doesn't return, `numLen, phoneMask = numberLen(3)` will cause that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `numberLen()` function only returns the tuple the caller is expecting when the user makes a valid input the first time; otherwise it calls itself recursively and does not return its returning value, which makes the function to return `None` by default, causing the exception when the caller tries to unpack it as a sequence.

You should change both occurrences of:

```
numberLen(i-1)
```

to:

```
return numberLen(i-1)
```

Comment: Also, the case of `valid and i == 0` looks like it will cause a similar problem.

Comment: @chunxu Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct?

Comment: Does it mean with "return" it actually called the function again? without this key word, it just go back to itself but not call it?

Comment: @chunxu You were already calling the function again with `numberLen(i-1)`. What `return` does is to simply return the returning value of `numberLen(i-1)` back to the current function's caller, which eventually is your main program that expects a sequence.